# Copy files without recreating subdirectories

Tags: windows, cmd

I have a directory that has about 100 subfolders and close to 2,000 files within those subfolders (up to 4 layers). The files are .txt or .log, and each extension has a unique file name.  I need to move or copy (whichever is faster) the files to the root of a different folder without recreating the subfolder structure like xcopy does. This is on Windows xp

Thanks in advance.

Existing:

```
Dir1\Folder1\000111.txt
Dir1\Folder2\000112.txt
Dir1\Folder3\000113.log
Dir1\Folder4\Dir2\000114.txt
Dir1\Folder4\Dir2\000115.txt
Dir1\Folder4\Dir2\000116.log
Dir1\Folder5\Dir3\000117.log
Dir1\Folder5\Dir3\000118.txt
Dir1\Folder5\Dir3\Dir4\000119.txt
Dir1\Folder5\Dir3\Dir4\000120.txt
Dir1\Folder5\Dir3\Dir4\000120.log
```

Required:

```
Dir9\000111.txt
Dir9\000112.txt
Dir9\000113.log
Dir9\000114.txt
Dir9\000115.txt
Dir9\000116.log
Dir9\000117.log
Dir9\000118.txt
Dir9\000119.txt
Dir9\000120.txt
Dir9\000120.log
```

Comment: You need to do it *like* XCOPY? Why not just use XCOPY?

Comment: i just tried with xcopy but it als copied the directory structures . That is not what i want .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about something like:

```
for /R %f in (*.txt,*.log) do copy %f dir9\%~nf
```

Issue this with `dir1` as your working directory.

Have a read of `for /?` to understand why this works.

When I work on `for` statements I tend to try them out first like so:

```
for /R %f in (*.txt,*.log) do @echo copy %f dir9\%~nf
```

Comment: what should i replace "dir1" asl input ?

Comment: @Micro just change directory to the root of the tree you want to work on

Comment: Whee an answer about doing something with files that uses `for` and *doesn't* do `for /f` over `dir`. That alone is worth a +1 :-)

Comment: If you want to keep file extensions during copy, you should use: for /R %f in (*.txt,*.log) do copy %f dir9\%~nxf