# Copy files without recreating subdirectories using Powershell

Tags: windows, powershell, command-line, batch-file

The solution here works for me if the command is executed at a command prompt:

[Copy files without recreating subdirectories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4845046/copy-files-without-recreating-subdirectories)

However, I get an error if the command is in a batch file:

"The following usage of the path operator in batch-parameter substitution is invalid %~nf"

How do you code this in Powershell?

Answer (score 4):

Replace any `%` with `%%` in a bat file.

So `%~nf` becomes `%%~nf`

Powershell equivalent:

```
gci -r .\test | ?{-not $_.PsIsContainer} | copy-item -Destination .\test2
```

Comment: Thanks!  How can I change these commands to accept the starting directory as a parameter?

Comment: In Powershell? use `param($source)` at top of script and use `$source` where you want. Read on Powershell paramters